# AIC far too low for poorly fitted polynomial

Tags: python, python-3.x, regression, non-linear-regression

I'm trying to find the best polynomial fit for a set of data. It calculates the AIC for each polynomial fit of a certain degree, and then chooses the one with the lowest AIC. To my knowledge (which I might be wrong about) the lowest value AIC I find is the best fit.

Here, I define my polynomials:

```
def p2(xData,a0,a1,a2):
    return a0 + a1 * xData + a2 * xData**2
def p3(xData,a0,a1,a2,a3):
    return a0 + a1 * xData + a2 * xData**2 + a3 * xData**3
def p4(xData,a0,a1,a2,a3,a4):
    return a0 + a1 * xData + a2 * xData**2 + a3 * xData**3 + a4 * xData**4
```

My function for computing the AIC:

```
def compute_AIC(yData,model,variables):
    residual=yData-model
    SSE=np.sum(residual**2)
    return 2*variables-2*np.log(SSE)
```

And my code for fitting polynomial fits for my data and choosing the best one:

```
def polynom_best_fit(xData,yData):
        print('Assessing if the best fit is higher order..')
        AICS=[]
        for i in [2,3,4]:
            params=[]
            params=poly.polyfit(xData,yData,i)
            print(params)
            if len(params) == 3:
                model_p2=p2(xData,*params)
                AICS.append(compute_AIC(yData,model_p2,3))
            if len(params) == 4:
                model_p3=p3(xData,*params)
                AICS.append(compute_AIC(yData,model_p3,4))
            if len(params) == 5:
                model_p4=p4(xData,*params)
                AICS.append(compute_AIC(yData,model_p4,5))
            else:
                continue
            print(AICS)
            best=np.where(AICS==min(AICS))
            best_model=[]
        for i in best:
            if np.where(AICS==min(AICS))[0][0] == 0:
                print('Second degree best fit')
                print('with AIC =', min(AICS))
                plt.plot(xData,model_p2,color='red')
                plt.scatter(xData,yData)
                plt.show()
                return min(AICS)
            if np.where(AICS==min(AICS))[0][0] == 1:
                print('Third degree best fit')
                print('with AIC =', min(AICS))
                return min(AICS)
            if np.where(AICS==min(AICS))[0][0] == 2:
                print('Fourth degree best fit')
                print('with AIC =', min(AICS))
                return min(AICS)
            else:
                print('Error')
```

However, when I execute this with my code that needs fitting, I get:

[image]

Which has a disarmingly low AIC value.

For a dataset that a piecewise linear regression clearly looked like the best fit to, the function created a polynomial which had a lower AIC value than my piecewise linear regression which had an Rsquared of over 0.99 but a AIC of around 12.

[image]

This doesn't pass sanity checks, so I must have done something wrong here. I think perhaps my definition of my polynomials or the way I defined my function that computes the AIC is wrong, or simply that my understanding of what AIC tells me about the best fit is wrong.

It could also be the case that even though my piecewise regressions tended to have very good Rsquared values, they had an enormous number of parameters (breakpoint 1, breakpoint 2, slope1, slope2, slope3, offset1, offset2, offset3 -- making 8 parameters or variables) which may had made the polynomials win out, but I'm still skeptical that my code is telling the truth.

Comment: Would you please post the data, or a link to the data?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have permission to do that, although to my knowledge the vague representation of the data in the scatter plots ought to suffice.

Answer (score 0):

From the plot joint to the question, the represented function y(x) looks like a piecewise function made of three segments.

A very easy method (no guessed initial value, no iterative calculus) is given in the paper : https://fr.scribd.com/document/380941024/Regression-par-morceaux-Piecewise-Regression-pdf

The case of this kind of piecewise linear function is treated pp.29-30. The paper is in French. The translation of the relevant page is given below :

[image]

[image]

Since the data is not given, an approximate data was obtained thanks to the scanning of the figure published by the OP.

The result is :

[image]

FOR INFORMATION :

Since the piecewise function is a non-linear function (even made of linear segments) , the linearization of the global regression is based on an integral equation :

[image]

For more explanation see the referenced document.